# AWS HTTP API Gateway: IAM Auth prevents me from using body data (403 error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using an HTTP Api Gateway and I have a problem with sending body data using POST (or any other) request.

I am using IAM Auth on my endpoint that is configured to use user roles from Cognito. I am trying to send a request to my endpoint using Postman.

If I send a POST request without body data, I get a 200 message and the application works as expected. When I add body data with content type json to that request, I get a 403 forbidden message. When I remove the IAM authentication on this route, it passes through without a problem and I get a 200 message again.

Why does IAM Authentication prevent me from using body data in my requests?

The permissions my user has is "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke",
                "execute-api:ManageConnections"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My lambda code is as follows (no issues as removing IAM auth works perfectly):

```
export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(event)
    };
}
```

I have tried setting CORS to allow headers 'content-type', 'host' and 'content-length'.

I have tried to disable IAM Auth on my route, which made the code work.